# how get symbol name and symbol from tradingview api

Tags: tradingview-api

I am making a simple site for my college project where a user simply send their requir symbol chart to be display in given format :**show me apple's stock data in 1 month interval**
So, i have to abstract symbol from user data and compare with symbol and send to the trading view.Show how can i achieve this.Thanks in advance